# What preconditions should be checked while adding/removing a listener?

Tags: java, design-patterns, observer-pattern

Imagine the following interface:

```
 interface Service {
   addListener(Listener l)
   removeListener(Listener l)
 }
```

Should I check for null values while add/remove? Is it a good idea on remove to check if the listener was registered before (e.g. listener B was never registered and should be removed)?

What behaviour helps developers here to identify problems without creating new ones like IllegalArgumentExceptions?

Comment: Take a look how listener adding and removal is handled in AWT. It is far from straightforward; you might get a few ideas. Checking for nulls is pretty cheap, though.

Comment: ^ the link: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/0b1c7f982cc0/src/share/classes/java/awt/AWTEventMulticaster.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost, you should be consistent with the framework convention. Java is a big world to be sure. I use Java for Android, and here the convention is rather permissive.

For example, `setOnClickListener` allows you to pass in `null` - this is a crude but nonambiguous way of removing the listener.

From Android source code:

```
public class View implements Drawable.Callback, KeyEvent.Callback, AccessibilityEventSource {
// [snip]

/**
 * Register a callback to be invoked when this view is clicked. If this view is not
 * clickable, it becomes clickable.
 *
 * @param l The callback that will run
 */
  public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener l) {
      if (!isClickable()) {
          setClickable(true);
      }
      getListenerInfo().mOnClickListener = l;
  }
```

Null is fine:

```
  /**
   * Return whether this view has an attached OnClickListener.  Returns
   * true if there is a listener, false if there is none.
   */
  public boolean hasOnClickListeners() {
      ListenerInfo li = mListenerInfo;
      return (li != null && li.mOnClickListener != null);
  }
```

Where multiple listeners are allowed, removing a listener is a tolerant operation, too:

```
/**
 * Remove a listener for layout changes.
 *
 * @param listener The listener for layout bounds change.
 */
public void removeOnLayoutChangeListener(OnLayoutChangeListener listener) {
    ListenerInfo li = mListenerInfo;
    if (li == null || li.mOnLayoutChangeListeners == null) {
        return;
    }
    li.mOnLayoutChangeListeners.remove(listener);
}
```

`mOnLayoutChangeListeners` is an `ArrayList`, and `ArrayList.remove(Object object)`  [doesn't crash](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(java.lang.Object)) on an inexistent item - it merely returns `false`.

The bottom line is the [robustness principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle) - be conservative in what you do, be liberal in what you accept from others.

When in doubt, I'd go with liberal, unless you have a solid reason not to. It's simplier and less surprising. Consistency is the king, and the [principle of astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) is based on consistency.

Any preconditions should be clearly documented. Your definition of `interface Service` doesn't by itself promise to throw exceptions when null is passed in.

`@NonNull` and `@Nullable` annotations may help to remove ambiguity, and they are supported by good IDEs such as IntelliJ Idea or Android Studio.

Comment: I disagree with being liberal in what you accept from others.  It's one thing to accept an `InputStream` or a `PrintWriter` and it's quite another to disregard nulls passed when a non-null value is expected.  Though I suppose to each his own.  In the end, I suppose so long as it is all documented and tested, everything is good.

Comment: @Neil I don't have a decisive opinion on the subject; it depends on the context. I'm more about "erring on the safe side" in my answer. Does crashing on nulls add any value to the system, or is it just a case of "enterprisey" code where every single method parameter is `@NonNull final` and a series `checkNotNull`s follows; just because?

Comment: As you said, it depends heavily on the context, though in my experience, if null is passed to a "addListener", something went wrong.  I'd just assume not ignore such an error and pretend everything is fine.  Something a lot worse than this could be at play that may affect other areas of the program.  That was what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

Good question.  I believe that such methods don't require its own check simply because:

1. `NullPointerException` is thrown should the event occur, so assuming you tested that case at least once, you would know if `null` were passed.
2. If you begin adding checks for `addListener` or `removeListener`, then you really would have to perform basic checks on every method in order to stay consistent throughout your code, which will have a negative impact on performance and readability.

I think the critical point behind checks like these is to ensure that parameters are what they should be within reasonable margins.  If you are the only one calling said method and in only a couple places, adding these checks is superfluous.  If anything, use junit to test specific methods utilizing these events to ensure that everything goes as expected.

When do you really need to perform these checks?

1. There is a serious possibility that the parameter getting passed may be `null`, and for one reason or another, you cannot check prior to passing it onto `Service.addListener`.  One possibility might be a library using reflection like Spring.
2. *Your* program is not calling these methods.  If you're writing a library to be used by others, it is a good practice to check all public methods that you intend to be called by the program using your library.
3. You're entering a rather sensitive part of your program where a lot could go wrong.  You need to be able to make certain assumptions about your input and you need for them to not be proven wrong, preferably not on a production computer during your lunch hour break.  (I call these sanity checks)

I'm mainly referring to `addListener`, though to answer your other question about `removeListener`, I usually don't find it necessary to know whether or not a listener was removed.  If that information is important, you could optionally return the listener that was removed or `null` otherwise, though I would only do so if that information were needed (and it usually isn't in my experience).

I hope that helps!